# Tensorflow 2.0 build fail in Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

## Environment

Windows 10

gtx 1050Ti

CUDA driver 441

CUDA tool kit 10.0

CuDNN 7

Python 3.5

Bazel 0.27.1

## Action

follow the official instruction. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

run :

```
C:\Users\admin\tensorflow>bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

## ERROR INFO

```
> **ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):** File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1304
> _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1132, in _create_local_cuda_repository find_cc(repository_ctx) File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 227, in find_cc
> _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 145, in _get_msvc_compiler find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path,
> "cl.exe").replace("\", "/") type 'NoneType' has no method replace()
> **ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered
> error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such
> package '@local_config_cuda//cuda':** Traceback (most recent call
> last): File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1304
> _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1132, in _create_local_cuda_repository find_cc(repository_ctx) File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 227, in find_cc
> _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 145, in _get_msvc_compiler find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path,
> "cl.exe").replace("\", "/") type 'NoneType' has no method replace()
> WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
> **ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl':
> no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent
> call last):** File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1304
> _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 1132, in _create_local_cuda_repository find_cc(repository_ctx) File
> "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 227, in find_cc
> _get_msvc_compiler(repository_ctx) File "C:/users/admin/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line
> 145, in _get_msvc_compiler find_msvc_tool(repository_ctx, vc_path,
> "cl.exe").replace("\", "/") type 'NoneType' has no method replace()
> INFO: Elapsed time: 31.315s INFO: 0 processes. FAILED: Build did NOT
> complete successfully (0 packages loaded) currently loading:
> tensorflow/tools/pip_package
```

Hope for your help

Comment: You may want to consider installing an pre-compiled version using Conda.  `conda create -n tf python tensorflow tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.@James